# Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-gesture-handler: None of the consumable configurations have attributes

Tags: react-native

i am getting the error Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-gesture-handler: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.in react native.

"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0" added to project

i already included these to my react native project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.6.0",
    "jest": "24.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

unable to install app on avd. i want to run this project in android virtual device(avd).

Comment: check you setting.gradle  and MainApplication.java may be you have linked library twice.

Comment: checked only linked in setting.gradle not in MainApplication.java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Windows, change this in your settings.gradle

```
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android')
```

instead of:

```
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\\node_modules\\react-native-gesture-handler\\android')
```

Ref:

https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/436

Comment: Have you cleaned your build?

Comment: Please use: `cd android` and `gradlew clean` in the root of your project

Comment: by using it i get this error 'D:\Latestproject\mytests\android\settings.gradle': 3: unexpected char: '\' @ line 3, column 133.
     s\react-native-gesture-handler\android')     it shows error in the position of   \ android

Comment: Remove the extra '\' and then try again in your settings.gradle.

Comment: by removing \ it shows the previous error Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-gesture-handler: None of the consumable configurations have attributes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191088/discussion-between-ashu-and-jrk).

Comment: This was my issue too, thanks so much, not sure what changed that required this to change since I checked out a known working git branch and ran into this issue.